# C beginner: string parsing

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 11:15:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: text/html

��(�ͱ���I�O����H�����ч��
                      �4�@�B�$���S
```

I want to extract "48" and the binary content.

Here's what I've tried sofar:

```
  //char* str contains the response
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting response into tokens:\n");
  pch = strtok (str,"\r\n");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
      printf ("%s\n",pch);
      pch = strtok (NULL, "\r\n");
  }
```

But I'm kinda stuck now... Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

edit:

Here's what I've done sofar:

```
char* pch;
char* pch2;
pch=strstr(buf,"Content-Length:");
pch2=strstr(pch,"\r\n");
```

How can I get the bit between these two pointers?

---

Edit: solution:

```
        char* pch;
        char* pch2;
        pch=strstr(buf,"Content-Length:");
        int i=0;
        char contLen[20];
        for(i=0;i<20;i++){
                char next=pch[strlen("Content-Length:")+i];
                if(next=='\r' || next=='\n'){
                        break;
                }
                contLen[i]=next;
        }
        printf("%d\n",atoi(contLen));
```

Comment: You can check http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ and the `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER` option

Comment: I want to avoid using CURL. I'm doing everything using sockets...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you instead search for the string `"Content-Length:"`, then from that point move forwards?

You can use `strstr()` to find the spot in `str`, then move the char pointer forward `strlen("Content-Length:")` positions, then read the value using `atoi()`.

There is no need to tokenize the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const char* http_header = 
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
"Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 11:15:21 GMT" \
"Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)\r\n" \
"X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9\r\n" \
"Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n" \
"Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n" \
"Content-Length: 48\r\n" \
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n" \
"mydata";

// will point to start of the actual data that following the http header
char* pdata = strstr((char*) http_header, "\r\n\r\n");
// will point to start of 'Content-Length' header
char* pcontent = strstr((char*) http_header, "Content-Length:");
// get the length of the data
int value = atoi(pcontent + 15);
```

Comment: Of course you should check so pdata and pcontent is valid before using them

Comment: ...and hope that nobody puts "Content-Length: -1" into their Server string?

Comment: Also there could be whitespaces between the Content-Length: and the actual value and the Content-Length could be all lowercase or all uppercase. Guess there is more...